# How to calculate time using a matrix in R

Tags: r, time, matrix

I have a matrix like below(the first row is:):

```
   method       start         i2         i3         i4         i5         i7        
1    "m1"   "17:19:02" "17:19:10" "17:19:18" "17:19:26" "17:19:36" "17:19:47"
```

So in each row I have the `method name` and then the `start time` and then the `end time` in *each* `i(x)` interval. I need to calculate the amount of time for each `i(x)` which is the `(start time - i(x) time)`. I think I need to change the format into time and then doing the minus but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#some data
df <- read.table(text='method       start         i2         i3         i4         i5         i7        
1    "m1"   "17:19:02" "17:19:10" "17:19:18" "17:19:26" "17:19:36" "17:19:47"
2    "m2"   "17:19:05" "17:19:10" "17:19:18" "17:19:26" "17:19:36" "17:19:47"',stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

m <- as.matrix(df)


#transform matrix to data.frame
df <- as.data.frame(m,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#melt to long format
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(df,id.vars="method")
#transform to date-time
df$value <- as.POSIXct(df$value,"%H:%M:%S",tz="GMT")

#calculate time differences
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(method),transform,timediff = value-value[variable=="start"])

   method variable               value timediff
1      m1    start 2013-02-11 17:19:02   0 secs
2      m1       i2 2013-02-11 17:19:10   8 secs
3      m1       i3 2013-02-11 17:19:18  16 secs
4      m1       i4 2013-02-11 17:19:26  24 secs
5      m1       i5 2013-02-11 17:19:36  34 secs
6      m1       i7 2013-02-11 17:19:47  45 secs
7      m2    start 2013-02-11 17:19:05   0 secs
8      m2       i2 2013-02-11 17:19:10   5 secs
9      m2       i3 2013-02-11 17:19:18  13 secs
10     m2       i4 2013-02-11 17:19:26  21 secs
11     m2       i5 2013-02-11 17:19:36  31 secs
12     m2       i7 2013-02-11 17:19:47  42 secs
```

Comment: You are right, but I didn't want to make any assumptions. (Can time only increase here? Are the colnames always following the pattern in the question?)